# Getting fired in Germany with a work visa, but I have a new job

Tags: visa, germany, working-visas

I am currently working in a hotel on Lubeck with a type D visa, but my hotel told me I have until the 11th of March and then they will lay me off!

I went to the Ausländerbehörde here in Lubeck and gave them my documents for a change of employer, but I have not received an answer and I don't plan to wait for them because I am forced to pack up and go live in the new hotel, at my new job.

I already have found a new job in Konstanz and my new boss has given me the green light to work for him. It's a hotel also, same position and pay.

What do I have to do to continue to work and stay in Germany? Am I allowed to go work for this new job or do I have to inform someone?

Comment: When you arrive in Konstanz, report to the immigration office there so that your case file can be transfered from Lübeck.

Comment: on my visa it says 19c ABS. 1 AUFENTHG I.V.M 26 ABS. 2 BESCHV, what does that mean, i forgot to mention i have barely worked here for 3 months and they already want to fire me, so is it okay if i stay and wait for my answer for a job switch? Anything else i have to do thats important?

Comment: Also forgot to mention, I have until the 11th of March to live in this hotel in Lubeck, after that if i dont get an answer from the asulanderbehorde I HAVE to move in Konstanz, in my new work place and live there! Are you sure my case can be transferred from Lubeck to the auslanderbehorde to Konstanz?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in §19c (1) AufentG or §26 (2) BeschV says you need prior approval to change your employer while in Germany.

As long as the visa is valid, report to the Immigration office (and registry office) after arrival in Koblenz.

---

**Sources**:

- [Act on the Residence, Economic Activity and Integration of Foreigners in the Federal Territory Residence Act (AufenthG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/index.html)

  - [§19c - Other employment purposes; civil servants](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0515)
- [Ordinance on the Employment of Foreigners (BeschV)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_beschv/index.html)

  - [§26 - Employment of certain nationals](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_beschv/englisch_beschv.html#p0213)

Comment: Oh so i dont need approval from the Auslanderbehorde? I can start work immediately?

Comment: For §19c (1) AufentG: no. That was done with the issuing of the visa.

Comment: Oh I see, but you told me I have to report to the immigration offices when I arrive in Konstanz! What documents do i need to bring and what should I tell them? I'm asking because I don't want to make any more mistakes!

Comment: @user30400 Passport, registration certificate and work contract. Then they will have your case file transfered.

Comment: I have another question, I am currently living here in the castle, but do I need to report to the rathaus or gemeinde here in this zone to update them? I registered in Lubeck and got a Steuer ID to go from tax class 6 to class 1, do I need to do that again here or no? I cannot risk getting a massive tax again!

Comment: @user30400 You must only report your change of address to the Meldebehörde. The SteuerID remains as is (nothing has changed)

Comment: Okay, and by the way I got my Zusttimung for working here. I am worried, what should I be doing now? Anything else that's important? Do I have to get a new visa, take a picture in some office? It says I can work from 13 March to 12 September 2024! Am I supposed to go the auslanderbehorde here and they have to give me a visa or is it safe to just continue working here?